# Webpack an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am using webpack with react. I have set up config for both production and development. I am getting this error in my src/index.js file:

ERROR in ./src/index.js 11:1
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:1)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

index.js

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
    // <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
    // </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

package.json

```
    "name": "client",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:9000",
    "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
        "bootstrap-css-only": "^4.4.1",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
        "history": "^5.3.0",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "react-twitter-login": "^1.5.0",
        "reactstrap": "^9.1.4",
        "universal-cookie": "^4.0.4",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
        "webpack": "^5.75.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack serve",
        "build": "webpack",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.20.2",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
        "babel-loader": "^9.1.0",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
        "css-loader": "^6.7.2",
        "node-sass": "^7.0.3",
        "postcss-loader": "^7.0.1",
        "postcss-preset-env": "^7.8.3",
        "saas": "^1.0.0",
        "sass-loader": "^13.2.0",
        "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
    }
}
```

webpack.common.js

```
const path = require("./path");

const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

const paths = require("./paths");

module.exports = {
    // Where webpack looks to start building the bundle
    entry: [paths.src + "/index.js"],

    // Where webpack outputs the assets and bundles
    output: {
        path: paths.build,
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/",
    },

    // Customize the webpack build process
    plugins: [
        // Removes/cleans build folders and unused assets when rebuilding
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),

        // Copies files from target to destination folder
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [
                {
                    from: paths.public,
                    to: "assets",
                    globOptions: {
                        ignore: ["*.DS_Store"],
                    },
                    noErrorOnMissing: true,
                },
            ],
        }),

        // Generates an HTML file from a template
        // Generates deprecation warning: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/1501
        // new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        //  title: "webpack Boilerplate",
        //  favicon: paths.src + "/images/favicon.png",
        //  template: paths.src + "/template.html", // template file
        //  filename: "index.html", // output file
        // }),
    ],

    // Determine how modules within the project are treated
    module: {
        rules: [
            // JavaScript: Use Babel to transpile JavaScript files
            { test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, use: ["babel-loader"] },

            // Images: Copy image files to build folder
            { test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$/i, type: "asset/resource" },

            // Fonts and SVGs: Inline files
            { test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf|svg|)$/, type: "asset/inline" },
        ],
    },

    resolve: {
        modules: [paths.src, "node_modules"],
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json"],
        alias: {
            "@": paths.src,
            assets: paths.public,
        },
    },
};
```

webpack.dev.js

```
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");

const common = require("./webpack.common");

module.exports = merge(common, {
    // Set the mode to development or production
    mode: "development",

    // Control how source maps are generated
    devtool: "inline-source-map",

    // Spin up a server for quick development
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        open: true,
        compress: true,
        hot: true,
        port: 3000,
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            // Styles: Inject CSS into the head with source maps
            {
                test: /\.(sass|scss|css)$/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: { sourceMap: true, importLoaders: 1, modules: false },
                    },
                    { loader: "postcss-loader", options: { sourceMap: true } },
                    { loader: "sass-loader", options: { sourceMap: true } },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
});
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env","@babel/preset-react", "react"],
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
  }
```

./public/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

<App/ > is a react class component
webpack.common.js,webpack.dev.js, webpack.prod.js  are all in one folder "config"

Comment: Could you post the full error message with the unexpected token it reports? Unexpected token means that the parser is dealing with some syntax that was not configured correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your npm script is not targeting your config file.

```json
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack serve --config webpack.dev.js",
        "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing rule for `js/jsx`

```
  { test: /\.(js|jsx)/, loader: "babel-loader", exclude: /node_modules/ },
```

you have to `npm install babel-loader`

Comment: OP added it in webpack.common.js.

Comment: how do you compile webpack?